# import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite' not working

Tags: react-native, expo

i am using expo to build a app.

here,

```
`import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
```

`const db = SQLite.openDatabase("db.db");`

is not working while

`import { SQLite } from "expo-sqlite";` is working.

when i use the first method, it is getting SQLite.openDatabase is not a function error.

actually what is the difference with these? anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';`  you are actually importing all the modules from the expo-sqlite by writing * as SQLite , and its stored as SQLite variable which then you are using to create an openDatabase.

But when you do `import { SQLite } from "expo-sqlite";` you are only importing the SQLite module from the expo-sqlite package. And after that you are using it to create a database.

Basically its like sometimes in some file you have multiple functions like suppose App.js

```
export const add =() => {

}


export const bol = () => {

}
```

Then suppose in Home.js you need to import ,

So if you want only the add function then you will do

```
import {add} from 'App.js'
```

or you want both so <

```
import {add,bol} from 'App.js'
```

and another way of importing both is by

```
import * as Func from 'App.js'
```

And now you can access each by `Func.add and Func.bol`

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts